# How to solve this circuit (phase shift across resistor)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, ac

I can't figure how do I proceed to solve this problem-

Vin is given as 2cos100t, Vout is 2cos(100t-π/2) and R=1k. C is to be found.

[image]

What I've done and where I'm stuck - I know that V- terminal will have a sinusoidal voltage with a certain phase shift due to the low pass filter and the opamp forcing V- = V+. I don't know how to proceed after that. I never encountered a problem where there's a AC voltage difference with phase shifted across a resistor! (Vin and V-)

Could anyone help?

Comment: Forget of all the stuff except the resistor and the capacitor connected to `+`. Can you tell how the waveform looks like on the capacitor?

Comment: Do you know how to use complex numbers to solve circuits with sinusoidal voltages? You could then find (or write formula) voltages at terminals.

Comment: "How to solve this circuit" By first learning the basics of op-amps, then you will solve it super easy. Go look up op-amp tutorials.. Maybe you also need to watch a tutorial about low-pass filters, but that should be all you need. This is really the absolute basics of electronics and you are not going to benefit anything from someone here handing you the answer..

Comment: @AlexVB "Do you know how to use complex numbers to solve circuits with sinusoidal voltages?" Absolutely no need for complex numbers here, just the knowledge that f = 1/(2\*pi\*r\*c) for an RC-filter.

Comment: @Vinzent I doubt that this is the expected solution for the task. But I'm curious how to use your formula. Will keep watching.

Comment: What is the phase shift?  What is the C required to get that phase shift?

Comment: @EugeneSh. At V+, voltage will be sinusoidal with amplitude 2*a/√(a^2+b^2) where a=1/RC and b=100., with a phase shift of tan^-1(-b/a)....By what I've learnt, Opamp will force this at V- too.

Comment: @Vinzent I'm not asking for an 'answer'. A straightforward 'answer' is not gonna help me understand the problem anyway. I've learnt filters and opamp and solved problems on them. That's why I said 'I never encountered a problem like this'

Comment: @aneetkumar It will force as you said. Therefore you can now tell the waveforms on both ends of the `-` resistor. And by that you can tell the waveform of the current flowing through it and the feedback resistor. And from there the output voltage.